# dynamicly load images in ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I have this code but rather than loading the same image, I want to load a different photo every time the ejs `for` loop outputs the template. Preferably also using ejs. The for loop is towards the bottom of the page. When it comes to the photos being used, just use a made-up file thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>



<!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="nav-extended">
<div class="nav-wrapper ">
  <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="badges.html"> <i class="material-icons prefix">shopping_cart</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="sass.html">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav-content">
  <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
    <li class="tab"><a href="">Top Items</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/orders">Tech</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/orders">Fashion</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/orders">Hobby</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/orders">Printed</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="/orders">Other</a></li>
    <a href="/order/pageadd" class="waves-effect waves-light btn sell"><i
        class="material-icons left">attach_money</i>Sell</a>

  </ul>

</div>
  </nav>
</div>
<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
  <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
  <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="row">
  <form class="col s12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
    <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="icon_prefix">Product Details</label>
  </div>
</div>
  </form>
</div>





<% for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++){ %>


<div class="card">

  <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
<div><img src="photo-storage/5bb0e02104309e02c814c9e8.jpeg"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-content">
<p class=" text-darken-4 mdl-typography--font-bold" id="NameProd" Name="NameProd"><%= order[i].NameOfProduct %></p>

<p>Price <%= order[i].OriginalPrice %> : <%= order[i].Discount %>% off</p>
  </div>

</div>
<% } %>

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how your data is set up (for example the structure of your `order` JSON data) but it might look something like this:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++){ %>                
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <div><img src="<%= order[i].ImageSrc %>" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-content">
      <p class=" text-darken-4 mdl-typography--font-bold" id = "NameProd" Name = "NameProd" ><%= order[i].NameOfProduct %></p> 

      <p>Price <%= order[i].OriginalPrice %> : <%= order[i].Discount %>% off</p>
    </div>

  </div>
<% } %>
```

Note changing the image source to `<%= order[i].ImageSrc %>`. Just like you're dynamically outputting the NameOfProduct, OriginalPrice and Discount values, if you have an image source value in your data you can dynamically output that too.

Also just FYI I believe you mean "load" not "loud". ;)